# Ignore user input outside of what's to be chosen from

Tags: c++, validation, exception, input

I have a program in which the user must make a selection by entering a number 1-5. How would I handle any errors that might arise from them entering in a digit outside of those bounds or even a character?

Edit: Sorry I forgot to mention this would be in C++

Comment: Umm, what programming language?

Comment: Sorry I left that part out. C++ is the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with this.  The following will produce an infinite loop if the user enters a letter:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int i=0;
  do {
    std::cout << "Input a number, 1-5: ";
    std::cin >> i;
  } while (i <1 || i > 5);
  return 0;
}
```

The issue is that `std::cin >> i` will **not** remove anything from the input stream, unless it's a number.  So when it loops around and calls `std::cin>>i` a second time, it reads the same thing as before, and never gives the user a chance to enter anything useful.

So the safer bet is to read a string first, and then check for numeric input:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int i=0;
  std::string s;
  do {
    std::cout << "Input a number, 1-5: ";
    std::cin >> s;
    i = atoi(s.c_str());
  } while (i <1 || i > 5);
  return 0;
}
```

You'll probably want to use something safer than `atoi` though.

Comment: This will do it... Thanks... I'll delete my answer.

Comment: How about wrapping that atoi in a try/catch?

Comment: @SteveSudit: `atoi()` cannot (should not) throw exceptions since it is a C runtime function.  Assuming that this is `std::atoi()` anyway.  `atoi` does not do anything useful in the case of a non-numeric string.  Use something like `strtoul` instead.

Comment: You should check if the extraction operator fails as well.  Enter EOF (Ctrl+D on UN*X, Ctrl+Z on Windows) once if you want to see an infinite loop.