# Using C isdigit for error checking

Tags: c++, c, loops, temperature

While using the boolean check for the int num this loop doesn't work. The lines after it go unrecognized. Enter and integer like 60 and it just closes. Did I use isdigit wrong?

```
int main()
{
    int num;
    int loop = -1;

    while (loop ==-1)
    {
        cin >> num;
        int ctemp = (num-32) * 5 / 9;
        int ftemp = num*9/5 + 32;
        if (!isdigit(num)) {
            exit(0);  // if user enters decimals or letters program closes
        }

        cout << num << "°F = " << ctemp << "°C" << endl;
        cout << num << "°C = " << ftemp << "°F" << endl;

        if (num == 1) {
            cout << "this is a seperate condition";
        } else {
            continue;  //must not end loop
        }

        loop = -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `isdigit(num)`, the `num` must have the ASCII value of a character (0..255 or EOF).

If it's defined as `int num` then `cin >> num` will put the integer value of the number in it, not the ASCII value of the letter.

For example:

```
int num;
char c;
cin >> num; // input is "0"
cin >> c; // input is "0"
```

then `isdigit(num)` is false (because at place 0 of ASCII is not a digit), but `isdigit(c)` is true (because at place 30 of ASCII there's a digit '0').

Answer (score 3):

`isdigit` only checks if the specified character is a digit. One character, not two, and not an integer, as `num` appears to be defined as. You should remove that check entirely since `cin` already handles the validation for you.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isdigit/

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to protect yourself from invalid input (outside a range, non-numbers, etc), there are several gotchas to worry about:

```
// user types "foo" and then "bar" when prompted for input
int num;
std::cin >> num;  // nothing is extracted from cin, because "foo" is not a number
std::string str;
std::cint >> str;  // extracts "foo" -- not "bar", (the previous extraction failed)
```

More detail here:
[Ignore user input outside of what's to be chosen from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975711/ignore-user-input-outside-of-whats-to-be-chosen-from/4975884#4975884)